# How to get to missing required keys: [:post_id] in nested comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have Group show page on which should be Posts and their corresponding Comments. My models are:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

In my views I display everything on group/show page so I use only create and destroy routes for posts and comments:

```
resources :groups
resources :posts, only: [:create, :destroy] do
 resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

My controllers look like:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
def show
 @group = Group.find(params[:id])
 @posts = @group.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @post = current_user.posts.build if user_signed_in?
 @comment = current_user.comments.build if user_signed_in?
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
def create
 @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
 @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
 if @post.save
   @group.posts << @post
   flash[:success] = "Post created!"
   redirect_to group_path(@group)
 else
   @posts = @group.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
   @users = @group.users
   render 'groups/show'
 end
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
 @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
 if @comment.save
  @post.comments << @comment
  flash[:success] = "comment created!"
  redirect_to group_path(@group)
 else
  @posts = @group.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @users = @group.users
  render 'groups/show'
 end
end
```

On group/show page I want to have group description and list of posts and their comments. Without comments everything works fine. But when creating comments I could not handle how to identify post_id of its corresponding post under which I want such comment create. My comments form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @comment, uri: post_comments_path do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, @post.id %>
 <%= f.input :content,label: false, placeholder: "add comment", error: false %>
 <%= f.button :submit, "Comment", class: 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

The only accessible id is group_id since I use its show page, but how to get to post_id?

Comment: do you have the same page where you rendered LIST of posts and it's comments? how do you do posting comments to specific/single post?

Comment: Yes that is what want to accomplish, but don't know how. It should be pretty much like here list of answers/posts and underneath list of comments.

Comment: Since your looping all the posts data and associated comments (like 2 iterations)[first posts.each do |post| >> next is post.comments do]. If you have that process, probably you will get the proper post_id of comments.

Comment: On the page group/show I've two forms one is for new post and below each post is form for new comment. The problem is that I couldn't create new comment because it can't find its corresponding post (resp. post_id) under which it should be created.

Comment: have you tried to put post_id in form path like post_comments_path(:post_id => @post.id), then catch the parameter in Controller.

Comment: I have it there as a hidden_field_tag. But the page doesn't send this param.

Comment: If you are getting the comment values but not the post_id which is not in comments fieldname, maybe you need to check the ActiveRecord Nested Attributes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yes I have already read it. But as I understand it it doesn't relate to my situation. I have two separete forms with two separate submit buttons. As I wrote it should be like here.

Comment: I understand, if you have separate form for comments posting, then the solution for getting the proper post_id is the way you render the associated comments in each post. Try to Inspect (right click on browser) and find the hidden field if the proper post_id is rendered. I think in hidden_field post.id, should be hidden_field_tag :post_id, (at)comment.post.id (since comment belongs_to :post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. After disassembling to parts I found that post_id was there but actually group_id was missing. Problem was when creating comment both post_id and group_id were necessary but since comments are nested I was not able to get to group_id. Solution is very simple:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @group = @post.group
```